# Google Data studio fails to present a table of "search keywords vs. top page ranke"

Tags: report, metrics, looker-studio, google-ads-api

I want to create such a table:

list of all search keywords of a specific advertiser. And for each column the metric of "absolute top page rate" for a different advertiser.

[image]

I have tried to start with a simpler table of keywords x one advertiser rates, but I get an error from data studio.

How can I create the desired table?

Thanks

> message: "absolute_top_of_page_rate is prohibited with entities: KeywordGroup. Measures should have explicit segmentation fields if prohibited entities are selected."
> trigger {
> string_value: "absolute_top_of_page_rate"
> }
> origin: INVALID_REQUEST

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the dimension `Search keyword` with `Keyword Text (Criterion)`.